# Can you craft badges or use card boosters for games you don't own?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

While you have to own a game to get card drops, drops are not the only ways to get cards from a game. You can trade them, you can buy them from the market or you can use a booster.

Do boosters work for games you don't own? Can you craft badges for games that you don't own?

Comment: games you don't have act like foil badges. As soon as you get one card of the set, the badge progress will appear. Once you have the full set you can craft it (regardless of game ownership)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can craft badges for games you don't own, yes. You'll need to trade for them or use the marketplace, but it's definitely possible. You can also open boosters, but you'll similarly need to trade for/buy them, since they only drop when you have received all your normal card drops for that game, but you can't get the normal drops without playing it, which requires you to own it.

Comment: You can trade them and market them. See http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=booster

Comment: Link just takes me to the Steam marketplace main page, but if you're confirming boosters as tradable, I'll edit the answer.

And now you've edited the link.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN:

- Craft badges for games you don't own
- Open Boosters for games you don't own

You CANNOT:

- Craft Boosters for games you don't own

Comment: To clarify:  As of a few months ago, it's possible to create badges using [Steam gems](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196251/what-are-steam-gems).  You can only create (craft) boosters for games you own.  But you can **open** boosters for any game, once you obtain the booster.